# MySQL where clause is causing an issue

Tags: mysql

I got an mysql query like so

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, min(price)   
WHERE price = 3000
```

My issue I am having is the min price changes when I use this where clause.

I am looking for way to have the absolute min price regardless of the where clause.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why then have the `WHERE` clause at all?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Perhaps an example would help.

Comment: Then remove your WHERE  clause.

Comment: The where clause is there cause the user is able to search by price and I us e the min price to display as a Starting At Price

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to accomplish.  You may want to post some sample data and the desired results.

Comment: It sounds as though you really want two queries: one through which you obtain the "Starting At Price" for display; and the other through which you obtain the user's search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested subquery

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.name, 
(SELECT t2.price
FROM table t2
),
FROM table t
WHERE t.price = 3000
```

Comment: I would just add that there is no need for t.name and t2.xxx if he select from same table, and after (SELECT MIN(price) FROM table) i would add AS min_price... otherwise that is solution for his problem :) So i would write query like this: SELECT DISTINCT name, (SELECT MIN(price) FROM table) as min_price FROM table WHERE price = 3000; GL

Comment: @AleksandarMiladinovic I wouldn't disagree with you there :-)

Comment: @Jonny Only important thing is that it's work, the idea how to solve problem. Tuning is just a bonus :)